# OSX Mavericks Finder Java Version

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks

This one has me pretty frustrated...

I've installed the Java JDK and got the command line successfully pointed at it. When I open jar files through the terminal it uses the correct JDK to run the jar.

However, when I attempt to open the same jar via double-clicking it in Finder, it uses a different Java executable! In this case, the one that's located at `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

How can I change what Java executable Finder is using?

Comment: right click => open with ?

Comment: On mavericks, in system preferences there should be a java configuration utility where you can select the version. On older versions it used to be in /Applications/Utilites/Java<Somehting> This allows you to configure the version of java to use for the system.

Answer (score 0):

**System Preferences > Java Control Panel > Java > View...** :

[image]

Comment: These configurations are not available to me. I don't think the Java Control Panel exists any longer in Mavericks, as far as I can tell...

Comment: I think Apple hides it — mine was hidden. In terminal: `cd /Library/PreferencePanes` and see if it's there. If it is just double-click it and it should install. Also check: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy/`; the file you're looking for is `JavaControlPanel.prefP‌​ane`